# Track users with PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ip, tracking, visitor-pattern

Have I missed any obvious things that you can log to keep track on your visitors (using PHP and JavaScript)?

- Can I get computer name?
- Can I get the country?
- Can I get the city?
- Postal code?
- Any other information that can be collected from certain browsers?

**PHP DOCUMENT :**

```
<script>

<?php 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$hostaddress = gethostbyaddr($ip);?>
<?php echo "document.write('The IP-adress: ' + " . "'" . $ip . "'" . " + '<br>');";?>
<?php echo "document.write('The host address: ' + " . "'" . $hostaddress . "'" . " + '<br>');";?>

document.write('The date: ' + new Date() + '<br>');
document.write('Get the entire URL of the current page: ' + location.href + '<br>');
document.write('This document was last modified on:' + document.lastModified + '<br>'); // good to know wich version of the page they have

if (document.referrer != ''){
document.write('The referrer of this document is: ' + document.referrer + '<br>')
}
else{
document.write('The is no referrer.<br>')
}

document.write('Number of URLs in history list: ' + history.length + '<br>')

// I know it doesn't allways return the right browser info, but it gives a good clue.
document.write("Browser name: " + navigator.appName + '<br>');
document.write("Browser version info: " + navigator.appVersion + '<br>');
document.write("Platform: " + navigator.platform + '<br>');
document.write("User-agent header sent: " + navigator.userAgent + '<br>');
document.write("Language of user: " + navigator.userLanguage);

document.write("Total Height: " + screen.height + '<br>');
document.write("Total Width: " + screen.width + '<br>');

document.write("Cookie: " + document.cookie + '<br>');

</script>
```

Comment: Note; keep in mind nearly *everything* is spoof-able.

Comment: You can get country and possibly city from the ip address, after scraping data from an ip address lookup site.

Comment: Thanks for the tip bozdoz! Are there any free ip address lookups (nice companies that doesn't do bad things with the ip-adresses i am checking...)?

Comment: Bracketworks, what do you mean with spoof-able? That visitor can pretent to be someone else?

Comment: Anyone can pretend to be someone else.

Comment: @Hakan: do what with the IP? They already have the database with locations. other than the fact that you've requested on a particular IP, what could they possibly do that they couldn't already do WITHOUT your lookup?

Comment: Marc B, I don't understand what you aks for. I want to track the IP-number for two reasons. 1) Be able to block some one's IP or if some one does anything elegal the police can look it up. 2) If the visitor delete there cookies, I might still be able to keep track on them through there IP-adress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of geolocation databases available. If you wish to go free there are some free databases too with less frequent updates than their paid counterparts, e.g. [MaxMind GeoLite](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country).

For more Google for [IP geolocation](https://www.google.com/search?q=ip%20geolocation%20free).